# Docker cp fails even if container:path is correct

Tags: linux, docker

I cannot copy a file from a running docker container but I can't figure our why:

```
$ docker exec code ls /etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml
/etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml
$ docker cp code:/etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml .
Error: No such container:path: code:/etc/loolwsd/loolwsd.xml
```

The error message is very common in several threads, but usually it is related to a bad container name or path, which I think is not my case. The very same `docker cp` command that is now failing used to work up to some days ago (it is in my bash history and I clearly remember I used it without issues).
Is there any hint about what might cause the issue? I recently upgraded the kernel but still didn't reboot the machine (it's a small production server), but I can't figure if this is relevant or not.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It works when I try to reproduce

Comment: Yes, as I wrote it used to work also for me but now it stopped and I'm trying to figure out what could be broken...

Comment: Are you sure that `code` container exists and is running? Try to prune your environment `docker system prune -a -f --volumes` and rebuild and run container again.

Comment: In my initial post you can see the successful outcome of `docker exec` which clearly states that the container is up and running and that container:path is correct.

Comment: I've restarted the machine and now `docker cp` works again. Thanks to those who tried to help!